# How to run JMeter tests using Maven

Tags: maven, jenkins, jmeter, jmeter-maven-plugin

I want to run Jmeter tests using Maven (in my case, it is Maven 2), so I can integrate it in Jenkins . I tried to do it using WSO2 Test Automation Framework following [this tutorial](http://nuwanwimalasekara.blogspot.com/2013/03/how-to-run-jmeter-test-scriptjmx-using.html)
but I got this error:

```
Missing artifact org.wso2.carbon.automation:org.wso2.carbon.automation.tools.jmeter:jar:4.0.8:compile
```

I also try another approach which is the use of the Jmeter plugin like they mentioned [here](http://wiki.apache.org/jmeter/JMeterMavenPlugin.)

I don't get any error but when i run my project in Maven using the goal verify, there is no test to run despite i put the TestJmeter.jm file in the src/test/java document.
For the maven-war-plugin i add it to my POM because i work on a dynamic web project.

Here is my POM file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>e-conseil</groupId>
  <artifactId>e-conseil</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
 <build>
       <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                  <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.8.1</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>jmeter-tests</id>
                            <phase>verify</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>jmeter</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
</build>

</project>
```

I don't know if I'm just missing something or this is a wrong approach.

Answer (score 1):

Put the test plan in src/test/jmeter, not src/test/java.

Comment: i don't have such a directory in my project structure. Do i have to create it?

Comment: Yes, you can create src/test/jmeter in your project

Comment: Yeah, the maven plugin will refuse to even run if the src/test/jmeter folder is not there already.

Answer (score 0):

I made a [complete example of running Jmeter from the jmeter-maven-plugin](https://github.com/djangofan/run-jmeter-with-plugins-via-build-tools) as a GUI.  And, of course, you can run command line also, without a GUI.